# how encode xdcam.mxf and set for mediainfo flag "standard: component"

Tags: ffmpeg, mediainfo

My goal is to encode an  XdcamHD 50Mb .mxf, with ffmpeg or ffmbc or bmx, and get the following Mediainfo technical and tag data

Format Settings, Matrix: Custom

Standard: Component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztuzh.jpg)

When I try to convert with FFmbc I get a correct XdcamHD in every aspects, except the following Mediainfo technical data:

Format Settings, Matrix: Default

Standard: PAL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRqMv.jpg)

The target file and my file analized whith ffprobe are identical

on the left target file on the right my encoded file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Exn.jpg)

and this is my code

```
ffmbc.exe -i %1 -tff -target xdcamhd422 -t 5 -y rewrapffmbc.mxf
```

When i try to convert with ffmpeg I obtain the same good file but if I read the technical and tag data in Mediainfo the flag "Standard:" has disappeared. Also in this case my file is being rejected from a Broadcast Company we deal with.

here is the ffmpeg code

```
ffmpeg.exe  -i %1 -r 25 -aspect 16:9 -pix_fmt yuv422p -color_primaries 1 -color_trc 1 -colorspace 1 -vcodec mpeg2video -non_linear_quant 1 -flags +ildct+ilme -top 1 -intra_vlc 1 -qmax 3 -lmin "1*QP2LAMBDA" -vtag xd5c -rc_max_vbv_use 1 -rc_min_vbv_use 1 -g 12 -b:v 50000k -minrate 50000k -maxrate 50000k -bufsize 3835k -bf 2 -trellis 1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -map 0:2  -map_channel 0.1.0:0.1.0 -map_channel 0.2.0:0.2.0  -map_channel 0.1.0:0.3.0 -map_channel 0.2.0:0.4.0  -map_channel 0.1.0:0.5.0 -map_channel 0.2.0:0.6.0  -map_channel 0.1.0:0.7.0 -map_channel 0.2.0:0.8.0 -c:a pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -ac 1 -map_metadata 0  -timecode 09:59:59:20 -y profilo-1.mxf
```

Can someone provide a solution or a workaround?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the custom quant matrix that you want to use? It's not a metadata string - it affects the encoding. The standard is a metadata flag which can be set manually

Comment: I haven't custom quant matrix,, How can I set manually the flag standard?

Comment: Add `-video_format component`

Comment: Thanks Gyan, it works. I wait the broadcaster's response.

Comment: For the broadcaster is fine